# Drupal Commerce Price Validation

Tags: commerce

I'm searching for the spot, where the price field validation is done as I want to do some more checks here. But I only found the commerce_product_product_form_validate function which is only doing the sku check, but not price. If anyone can point me to the right file / function I would be very glad.

Comment: You'll find information on that in this thread http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22952/custom-validation-for-a-form

Comment: My problem is, that I don't want to add a new validation but edit the old one which is checking for required fields. But I can't find where this is done. Commerce isn't using form_alter as far as I found out.

Comment: What exactly do you want to change? Changing a modules default behavior by editing the modules code is a big no no :)

Comment: I know. But I want price to be an non-mandatory field. As this isn't possible I have to change the check to set the price to a default value (0) when no price is set. I'm now on a workaround with a core-hack in drupals form.inc, which is pretty bad, but as commerce isn't giving me the chance to set a default price I'm stuck with that :(

Comment: Or is there a chance to bring in the standard _form_validate into commerce as an override?

Comment: You could just set the #default_value for the price field to 0, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21627/programmatically-set-the-default-value-for-a-field

Comment: Maybe I tried it in the wrong position, but I tried it before and it seems to not work at all. I'll give it another try, cause this would be much better than my actual solution.